# Why is $ \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = \frac{1}{r^2} $?

Tags: vectors, vector-fields

I know it's surely a beginner's question but I don't see why you can write 
\begin{align}
\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = \frac{1}{r^2}\cdot \frac{|\vec{r}|}{r}
\end{align}
Could someone explain it please? It would help understand quite a few things ...

Comment: You are missing the position unit vector on the right side of your equation.

Comment: What do you mean? Or better: how (and why) can I rewrite $\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}$.

Comment: You cannot have a vector equal to a scalar. You either need to replace the vector with its magnitude as @HiddenBabel does, or you need to add the unit r vector to the right side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you wrote is not true. The $r$ without an arrow is only a scalar - the *length* of a vector. So the right-hand side is a scalar. The left-hand side is a vector $\vec{r}$ divided by its length cubed. So the result is still a vector. However, the length of the resulting vector in the left *is* $1/r^2$. This is because the $\vec{r}$ carries a length of $r$ with it. So if you take the norm, you get

$$\frac{|\vec{r}|}{r^3} = \frac{r}{r^3} = \frac{1}{r^2}$$

Comment: Ah ok, well our teacher literally always writes it the way I wrote it in the question! 

How can I rewrite $\frac{\vec{|r|}}{r}$?

Comment: That is the unit vector, which is $\vec{r}$ scaled to length 1. It is written as $\vec{\hat{r}}$. If you put that on the right hand side of your first equation, then the equation is correct.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought the unit vector is $\hat{r} = \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|}$.

Comment: A vector can be represented as, $\vec{r}= |\vec{r}|\hat{r}$. $|\vec{r}|$ shows the magnitude of the vector and $\hat{r}$ shows the direction.

Comment: Oh I misread what you​ wrote. $|\vec{r}|/r$ is just 1, then.

Comment: I see that. So: $\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = \frac{\hat{r}\cdot |\vec{r}|}{r^3}$ $=$  $\frac{1}{r^2}\cdot \hat{r}$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The point is: I must show $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{m\alpha} \cdot \vec{p}\times \vec{L} - \frac{1}{r}\cdot {\vec{r}} ) = 0$. So I can write $\frac{1}{r}\cdot {\vec{r}}$ = 1?

Comment: No, because the left hand side of the last equation is a vector and the right hand side is not.

Comment: I mean $\hat{r}$ instead of 1. Sorry ... 
(Just confused myself quite a bit ...)

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\vec{r}}{r}=\frac{1}{r^2} \vec{u_r}$$
where $\vec{u_r}$ is an unitary vector with the direction of $\vec{r}$

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is: being $\overline r= r\mathbf{\widehat r}$, then

$$\frac{\overline r}{r^3}=\frac{r\mathbf{\widehat r}}{r^3}=\frac{\not r\mathbf{\widehat r}}{r^{\not 3\,2}}=\frac{\mathbf{\widehat r}}{r^{2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Answer: **Equality: $\frac{\vec r}{r^3}= \frac{1}{r^2}$ is not true**

**Explanation:** A vector quantity (having both magnitude & direction) & a scalar quantity (having only magnitude) can never be equated.

Now, $\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ is a vector quantity while $\frac{1}{r^2}$ is a scalar quantity hence 
$$\therefore \frac{\vec r}{r^3}\ne \frac{1}{r^2}$$

Similarly $|\vec r|=r$ is the magnitude of vector quantity $\vec r$ so $\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{|\vec r|}{r}$ is a scalar quantity 
$$\therefore \frac{\vec r}{r^3}\ne \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{|\vec r|}{r}$$
However your equality seems to probably be similar to 
$$\frac{|\vec r|}{r^3}= \frac{1}{r^2}$$